# ResultSet and JTable - R2XML ignores the first value

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I made a code in Java in Netbeans to insert information in a table with the result of the Database, however the first value returned is not applied in the table, can someone help me?

Only three data appear in the table:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOl44.png)

If I run the same SQL directly on PHPMyAdmin it returns this four data:
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EAZP.png)

**Code where SQL runs in Java:**

```
public ResultSet getInfos(){
        VIEW.Inicio Inicio = new VIEW.Inicio();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_denuncia WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY prioridade DESC, id ASC LIMIT ?";
        
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = this.getConexao().prepareStatement(SQL);
            stmt.setInt(1, 10);
            
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
            
            if(res.next()){
                return res;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException erro) {
            throw new RuntimeException(erro);
        }
    }
```

**Code where arrow in the table:**

```
Tabela_TOP10.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));
```

Does anyone know how it should be done to show ALL the values ​​returned?

Comment: The Portugese language is beautiful, but it's better either to translate the question to English or move it to https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Did you commit the data in MySQL Workbench, and are you sure your connecting to the same database? Please provide a [mre]. Also be aware that you're current code is leaking resources, and the `ResultSet` shouldn't be returned from that `getInfos` (it is one cause of resources leaks, as is forgetting to close the statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included the code of your `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel()` method, but I strongly suspect it looks something like this:

```java
public YourTableModel resultSetToTableModel(ResultSet resultSet) {
    YourTableModel tableModel = new YourTableModel();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        // read a row out of the result set and add it to the table model.
    }
    // ...
}
```

Note the call to `resultSet.next()`.  This is a standard way to process rows out of a `ResultSet`: you check to see if there is a next row to be read (which moves the result set onto the next row) and if so, you read values out of that row, do something with them, and then loop back to process any more rows.

Note also that your `getInfos()` method *also* calls `.next()` on your result set, before it gets passed to `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel()`.  So before your code starts processing any data from the result set, `.next()` has been called on it twice.  This causes it to skip the first row.

I really don't see why you have this in your code:

```java
            if(res.next()){
                return res;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
```

It would be far simpler to replace it with

```java
            return res;
```